# "Estender" e/and "Extender". Diferenças/Differences?

Tags: ortografia, significado

Sempre foi uma dúvida que tive. Uso as duas formas, mas não sei se a diferença de grafia influencia em algo no significado.

---

It was always a doubt that I had. I use the two forms, but I don't know if the spelling difference influences into something in meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estender é a forma correta de dizer, uma vez que, Extender não existe.

## [Estender](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/estender)

> (latim extendo, -ere) verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Dar mais superfície a. = ALARGAR, ALONGAR
> 2. Desenrolar.
> 3. Esticar.
> 4. Puxar.
> 5. Desdobrar.
> 6. Deitar ao comprido.
> 7. Prolongar.
> 8. Desenvolver.
> 9. Propagar.
> 10. Difundir.
> 11. Fazer dar estenderete.
> 12. [Figurado]  Vencer em discussão. verbo intransitivo
> 13. Dilatar-se.
> 14. Cair. verbo pronominal
> 15. Ocupar um espaço em extensão. = ALONGAR-SE, PROLONGAR-SE
> 16. Alastrar-se.
> 17. Cair.
> 18. Estatelar-se.
> 19. Divulgar-se.
> 20. Durar.
> 21. Fazer má figura, dizer tolices ou erros graves em lição, exame, discurso, etc. = ESPALHAR-SE

Fontes: [Extender no dicionário](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/extender), [Estender ou extender](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/extender-ou-estender/)

Comment: O [terceiro link que disponibilizou](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/extender-ou-estender/) tem bons exemplos e uma explicação bastante interessante: "palavras cognatas de estender são, porém, escritas maioritariamente com x, como **extensão**, **extenso**, extensível, extensor, extensibilidade,… A explicação desta situação poderá estar na **introdução das palavras no português em diferentes épocas** [...]"